How do I remove the header on a react native (expo) page?
I have a Tab.Navigator on my page and I can hide the header with headerShown: false.
But there is another header with the name "index", I don't know how to remove it. Picture of my problem
My codes:
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import React , {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { TabBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import searchApp from './search';
import HomeApp from './main';
import saveApp from './save';
import profileApp from './profile';

import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function HomeScreen() {

  useEffect(() =>{
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
  })
  
  const [headerShown, setHeaderShown] = React.useState(false);

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    yr: require('../assets/fonts/yr.ttf'),
  });
  return (

    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeApp}
              options={{
                header: () => null,
                title: 'MainPage',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
                  <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'film' : 'film-outline'} color={color} />
                ),
                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#00925d'
              }}
            />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={searchApp} 
              options={{
                title: 'Search',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
                  <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'search' : 'search-outline'} color={color} />
                ),
              }}/>
                    <Tab.Screen
        name="save" component={saveApp} 
        options={{
          title: 'Bookmark',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'bookmark' : 'bookmark-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="profile" component={profileApp} 
        options={{
          title: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'person-circle' : 'person-circle-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>

    
  );
}

